# How to execute managed bean method on selectOneMenu change?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el, methodnotfound

I have the following Managed Bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {

    public void mostrarCentroSeleccionado() {
        System.out.println("Value changed");
    }

}
```

And inside my .xhtml file the following selectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{MyBean.centros.idcentro}" >

    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{MyBean.mostrarCentroSeleccionado}" />

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un centro" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.centros}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

When I run that code I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your listener doesn't take the event, you should use `listener="#{myBean.mostrarCentroSeleccionado()}"`

Comment: The full code will make this question unreachable... in fact @Holger answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the tag:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{MyBean.function()}"/>
```

The function must have "()" becouse I´m not taking the event.

Answer (score 0):

If Holger's solutions works out, its fine.

BUT: It is horrible to start start a Java Class Name with lower case letter. You can start with a capital letter and JSF will manage it for you, so you can still use
    listener="#{myBean.mostrarCentroSeleccionado()}"
If this does not meet your requirements you can use
    @ManagedBean(name = "myBean ")
Instead of myBean you can choose what ever you want.

Comment: If you know a little about PrimeFaces, you will understand that the point here is in one of two options.

1- Something missing or wrong at a xhtml tag or attribute.
2- A problem with the method to execute

Anything else is just to put you in context. It´s not relevant or important.